# Is there anyway to create playlists on Spotify using a command line tool?

Tags: unix, spotify

I want to create a playlist through the command line, but I appear to need to use the "Authorization Code Flow" method of authentication to be able to do this. The only way I can think to do that, is with a full web app through the browser, but I just want to make a command line tool without any of that hassle.

Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You do indeed need to use the Authorization Code Flow. However, that doesn't mean you need to build a web app.

#### Method 1: Prompt from command line, a la Spotipy

Check out the way Spotipy, a 3rd party Python library implements their authentication: https://github.com/plamere/spotipy. It uses the command line to prompt for authentication, then gets users to copy the URL back. This could be an easy workaround if you don't want to fully implement an authorization flow yourself. I recommend going through their quick start to get an idea of a non- web app implementation.

(They even have an example for "Create a playlist", maybe you can just use and build off that? https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/create_playlist.py)

#### Method 2: Get an access token for your account only

The Authorization Guide states the following:

> Accessing your data without showing a login form
>
> I want to interact with the web API and show some data on my website.
>   I see that the endpoints I need authorization, but I don’t need/want a
>   login window to pop-up, because I want to grant my own app access to
>   my own playlists once. Is there any way of doing this?
>
> You basically need an access token and a refresh token issued for your
>   user account. For obtaining a pair of access token / refresh token you
>   need to follow the Authorization Code Flow (if you need a certain
>   scope to be approved) or Client Credentials (if you just need to sign
>   your request, like when fetching a certain playlist). Once you obtain
>   them, you can use your access token and refresh it when it expires
>   without having to show any login form.

So, if you only need access for your own account, grab any of the simple tutorials from the internet, follow it, and get an access token. You can then use that access token to make calls.